# How to add data source to Data Grid View in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

In Windows Form Application I have two text boxes and 1 button and 1 Data Grid View.

I am trying that on Button Click to show data in dataGridView on the basis of numbers given in Text Boxes

I am not getting any error and I can't see any data in data grid view.

Here is my code:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 SqlDataAdapter da_for_Branch;
 DataSet ds_forBranch = new DataSet();

 SqlConnection con;

con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Test ;Initial Catalog=combit_cRM_Solution3;Integrated Security=True"); 

da_for_Branche = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Distinct(BusinessSectorID),Description_DE " +     
                                    " FROM BusinessSector5 " +
                                    " WHERE BusinessSectorID>= '"+ TxtBoxFrom.Text + "' " +      
                                    " AND BusinessSectorID<='" + TxtBoxTo.Text + "' " +
                                    " ORDER BY BusinessSectorID ", con);


da_for_Branche.Fill(ds_forBranches);

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds_forBranches;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly bind the Dataset as a data source to the grid. You can only bind table in a dataset. In your cause you should bind the table in index 0.

```
//Wrong
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds_forBranches;
```

---

```
//Right
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds_forBranches.Tables[0];
```

Comment: you CAN use a DataSet as DataSource for a DataGridView ... but you have to set the DataMember property to the name of the table then ... like this: dataGridView1.DataMember = ds_forBranches.Tables[0].TableName;    although I think that a DataSet is not really necessary in the code above ... a simple DataTable would be enough